# form authentication in java

Tags: java, jsp, forms-authentication, struts-1

I am  using form authentication to my website. the scenario is like when we hit the login page  if the username pwd is not correct the user will get redirected to the login page again if successful the user will get redirect to the index.jsp page
The issue is the when the username password is incorrect the user is getting redirected to login page correctly but when the combination is correct, index page is not coming up.

Below is the securityfilter-config.xml code .

```
<securityfilter-config>

 <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
 <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>
            georegister
        </web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/beheer/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/interface/HarvestSource*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>beheerder</role-name>
        <role-name>superbeheerder</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <!--
    <user-data-constraint>
    <description>SSL not required</description>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    -->
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>
            GetFile
        </web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/beheer/servlet/GetServiceFileServlet</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>superbeheerder</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <!--
    <user-data-constraint>
    <description>SSL not required</description>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    -->
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.do</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.do</form-error-page>
        <form-default-page>/beheer/index.do</form-default-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<realm className="nlsi.register.services.SecurityRealm"/>

</securityfilter-config>
```

Also I am defining that in struts config file

```
      <action path="/index" forward="base.beheer.index"/>        
      <action path="/" forward="/beheer/index.do"/>
```

Please let me know how can I solve this issue.

Comment: "but when the combination is correct, index page is not coming up." - what  does happen? 404, 500? etc etc

Comment: @Lawrence, yes 404 error is coming up, and the url is like www.example.com/beheer/ only ,whereas it should be like www.example.com/beheer/index.do.  index.do is not coming in the url.